# Could a balloon be thrown from the moon to the earth by a man or woman or machine?

Tags: material-science, centripetal-force, moon, escape-velocity, three-body-problem

Is it physically possible for a three meter radius balloon to be whirled about on a string by a person or if necessary a machine (perhaps held by the person) standing on the surface of the moon and released with a velocity such that it escapes the moon's gravity and passes near enough to the Earth to be seen with the naked eye?

Comment: The angular resolution of our eyes is somewhere around 0.3 m at 1 km, so we could see this ball at a maximum of 20 km, which is roughly the top of cumulonimbus clouds.

Comment: What is the downvoting for?

Comment: @HiddenBabel That is during the day. At night, if illuminated by the sun it could surely be seen at a much greater distance.

Answer (score 3):

The Moon's escape velocity is about [$2.38 km/s$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity#List_of_escape_velocities). Nobody can throw anything at that speed.

A suitable machine can, of course, do it - as evidenced by the fact that we've been to the Moon and back.